# launchctl fails with "Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error", if the app is signed with sandbox:

Tags: python-3.x, nuitka, macos-sonoma, keepalived, launchdagent

I am implementing parental control app via python 3.9 for macOS. Therefore I want to use
launch agent to keep my application always alive (app reopened automatically after reboot pc
and protected against to be closed via activity monitor.) I want to give keep alive enabling and disabling option to parents that they can deactivate or activate it in the app GUI.

I achieved to keep alive my app standalone signed app without sandboxing(or via Terminal command) but if I sign it with sandbox then I get following error for "launchctl load" and "launchctl bootstrap" commands which are executed in the application
**"Load failed: 5: Input/output error"**

**My steps without Sandbox which works fine:**

1- Create a com.test_gui.macos.plist file under /Library/LaunchAgents with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test_gui</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>open</string>
        <string>-g</string>
        <string>-a</string>
        <string>/Applications/test_gui.app</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

2- create a python file for launch agent activation (I know either launchctl load or bootstrap
should be used but I used both of them to test both.):

```
import subprocess
cmd = "launchctl enable gui/501/test_gui"
response = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
time.sleep(2)
cmd = "launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/com.test_gui.macos.plist"
response = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
time.sleep(2)
cmd = "launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchAgents/com.test_gui.macos.plist"
response = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
time.sleep(50)
```

3- Create standalone app via nutika:

```
python3.9 -m nuitka --run --standalone --macos-disable-console --macos-create-app-bundle
\--macos-app-mode=ui-element --enable-plugin=pyside6 --macos-app-icon=/Users/emre/Documents/MrProtect/icons/app_icon.png
\--include-data-dir=icons=icons test_gui.py
```

4-Create a .sh file to sign app without sandboxing:

```
#!/bin/sh

# 

# Creates ./dist/HelloAppStore.app

# 

APP_PATH="/Users/emre/Documents/tests/Deployment/test_gui.app"
SIGNING_IDENTITY_APP="Apple Development: Emre Guenay (xxx)"
PASSWORD="xxx"
codesign -s "$SIGNING_IDENTITY_APP" -f \
"$APP_PATH/Contents/MacOS/Python"
codesign -s "$SIGNING_IDENTITY_APP" -f \
"$APP_PATH/Contents/MacOS/test_gui"

exit 0
```

5-execute sh file and see following output:
/Users/emre/Documents/MrProtect/tests/Deployment/test_gui.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: replacing existing signature
/Users/emre/Documents/MrProtect/tests/Deployment/test_gui.app/Contents/MacOS/test_gui: replacing existing signature

6-copy paste signed standalone app(without sandbox) file under /Applications/

7-execute app and try to close app via activity monitor and observe that the app is reopened
automatically. so the launch agent works fine

**Failed Steps(Sign the same app with sandbox and observe that both launchctl load and bootstrap returns "Load failed: 5: Input/output error")**

8- create an app.entitlements file with following content:

```
\<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?\>
\<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"\>
\<plist version="1.0"\>
\<dict\>
\<key\>com.apple.security.app-sandbox\</key\>
\<true/\>
\</dict\>
\</plist\>
```

9-Create a .sh file to sign app with sandboxing:

```
#!/bin/sh

# 

# Creates ./dist/HelloAppStore.app

# 

APP_PATH="/Users/emre/Documents/tests/Deployment/test_gui.app"
SIGNING_IDENTITY_APP="Apple Development: Emre Guenay (xxx)"
PASSWORD="xxx"
codesign -s "$SIGNING_IDENTITY_APP" -f \
\--entitlements app.entitlements \
"$APP_PATH/Contents/MacOS/Python"
codesign -s "$SIGNING_IDENTITY_APP" -f \
\--entitlements app.entitlements \
"$APP_PATH/Contents/MacOS/test_gui"

exit 0
```

10-execute sh file and see following output:
/Users/emre/Documents/MrProtect/tests/Deployment/test_gui.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: replacing existing signature
/Users/emre/Documents/MrProtect/tests/Deployment/test_gui.app/Contents/MacOS/test_gui: replacing existing signature

11-execute app and try to close app via activity monitor and observe that the app is closed
although app started the launch agent.

12-you can re-execute app under /Applications/test_gui.app/Contents/MacOS folder with
"./test_gui" or even with sudo "sudo ./test_gui" commands
you would see following error message for both launchctl load and bootstrap returns:
"Load failed: 5: Input/output error". So if you close the app, it will not be re-opened

**My 2 questions:**

1-Is there any other method different than launch agent for keep alive? I researched it in internet but I could not find any other method unfortunately.
Moreover launch agent is not user friendly anyway, with the reason that sandboxed apps cannot copy paste any files
under LaunchAgents folder automatically. I am planning to provide my plist file to users that they can copy paste the file
themself into launch agent folder out of sandbox.

2-How can i get rid of "Load failed: 5: Input/output error", thereby I can proceed at least with lanuchctl?

What I have tried additionally:

1-I have also tried to use these linux commands, before executing my sandboxed standalone app file:

```
sudo -S chown 600 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.test_gui.macos.plist
sudo -S chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchAgents/com.test_gui.macos.plist
```

2-I have already given security fulldisk access to my test_gui app, but it also did not work

My Requirements:

Nuitka:

```
1.9rc5
Commercial: None
Python: 3.9.12 (v3.9.12:b28265d7e6, Mar 23 2022, 18:22:40) 
Flavor: CPython Official
Executable: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
OS: Darwin
Arch: x86_64
Version C compiler: /usr/bin/clang (clang).
```

macOS Sonoma:
14.2.1

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm getting EIO = "Input/output error" for `launchctl bootout` on Sonoma as well. It used to work on previous OS.

Comment: No unfortunately not.